# Why does access-token changes constantly in POST requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have installed [devise_token_auth gem](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) for user authentication for API calls.

I've done standard procedure in Postman -> Logged in through POST request with email and password and get uid, client and access token.

Again I try to log in to path which is restricted if user isn't logged in(with uid, client and access token in header)  and I get 401 unauthorized error

```
{
    "errors": [
        "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
    ]
}
```

I also add

```
config.change_headers_on_each_request = false
```

in config/initializers/devise_token_auth.rb.

What I notice is that my access-token constantly changes(in every POST request when I sign in with mail and password).
Is it normal or I'm getting this error because of that? If not what could be the problem here?

Comment: you'll get different tokens every time you log in. Read https://devise-token-auth.gitbook.io/devise-token-auth/config/initialization, you'll find the `change_headers_on_each_request` in case that's what's happening to you.

Comment: That's the problem. I added that to `false` in initializer and again access-token changes everytime I send request

Comment: are you then getting on every request you make ?, or is it changing just every time you log in ?

Comment: Only when I'm log in in Postman through post request

Comment: so, yeah, that's fine, if you're logging in you'll get a new token every time.

Comment: it is the client's duty to properly handle a token, if it is still valid then don't log in again.